# Update function on page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple javascript function that detects the page scrolling.

Everything works.

The only omission is that when the page is refreshed the scroll is not preserved so needs reinstating.

I thought it might be something as simple as replacing the direct call to `docScroll() in pub.init` with something like `$(window).on("load", docScroll()); in setBindings` but unfortunately this doesn't work.

Anyone offer advice?

```
var scroll = function () {
    var pub = {}, timeout = null;

    function reset() {
        if (typeof (timeout))
            clearTimeout(timeout);

        timeout = setTimeout(function () {
            docScoll();
        }, 200);
    }

    function docScroll() {
        $body = $("body");
        var headerHeight = $("#header").height();

        $(document).scroll(function () {
            if ($(window).scrollTop() > headerHeight) {
                $body.addClass("scrolling");
            }
            else {
                $body.removeClass("scrolling");
            }
        });
    }

    function setBindings() {
        $(window).on("resize", reset);
    }

    pub.init = function () {
        setBindings();
        docScroll();
    }

    return pub;
} ();
```

Comment: When do you call init()?

Comment: init is called inside document.Ready

Comment: why is this not sufficient?

Comment: When the page is refreshed the variables are reset. If you need to store data between refreshes you can try `localStorage` and then on document ready or page load event read the previous data and scroll as appropriate.

Comment: @JohnOhara Oh! and there is a typo in the timeout handler

Comment: you could also an url hash on scroll finish and on reload you parse it and scroll to that position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scroll event handler should be set once. So I would do something like this:

```
var scroll = function () {
    var pub = {};

    function docScroll() {
        var $body = $("body");
        var headerHeight = $("#header").height();

        if ($(window).scrollTop() > headerHeight) {
            $body.addClass("scrolling");
        }
        else {
            $body.removeClass("scrolling");
        }
    }

    function setBindings() {
        $(document).scroll(docScroll);
    }

    pub.init = function () {
        setBindings();
        docScroll();
    }

    return pub;
} ();
```

Comment: tested and works without the complications if storing variables. I added the resize event back - calling docScroll() for completeness. The header changes size on orientation. Thanks for assisting.